# Multi node private local ethereum and send transaction

Tags: go-ethereum

Have a 3-node local private cluster - Nodes A, B and M (miner). Added M as a peer to both node A and node B. When send a transaction transferring 1 ether from node A to node B - eth.sendTransaction in node A. See there is one pending transaction in node A while no pending in either node B or node M. My understanding was that all transactions propagate and node M would mine that and add to the Block. See 0 pending transactions in node B or node M. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you confirm that you see M with `admin.peers`?

Comment: Node M shows both the node A and node B as peers.

Comment: Started the miner using the command: geth --mine --minerthreads 1 --etherbase "xxx" --gasprice 1000000 --gpomin 1000000 --gpomax 1000000 --identity "miner" --datadir ./data/miner --networkid 12345 --maxpeers 2 --nodiscover --ipcdisable --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 30001 --port 8081 --verbosity 4 console, where xxx is the miner account address

Comment: started 2 nodes A and B using the command: geth --identity <node-name> --datadir ./data/<A or B> --etherbase "xxx" --networkid 12345 --maxpeers 2 --nodiscover --ipcdisable --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport <30002 and 30003> --port <8082 and 8083> --verbosity 3 console

Comment: If the sendTransaction is performed on node M, then the transaction is mined and all the node A, B, and M reflect the appropriate ether balances.

Comment: try to run the node m normally and then after sending the transaction start mining. besides which geth do you have,? and try also to remove the -nodiscover  option

Comment: Geth Version: 1.4.16-stable

Answer (score 2):

it seems to be a bug in geth : read https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2769

Comment: Tried starting all the nodes A, B, and M as normal and added peers M to node A and B as well as peer A to node B. This way all the nodes are connected with 2 peers. Now started the miner on node M and send a transaction from node B. Nothing happens ... this is a serious bug IMHO. How is one supposed to setup and test ethereum in an enterprise ?

Comment: use another client parity or eth

Answer (score 0):

You should have multiple nodes to have complete private network setup, single miner will not work as it violates ethereum protocol , try with multiple nodes it should work, but two miners cannot run under single windows OS , please follow setup for running multiple miner below

[Setting up private multi node / miner ethereum network](http://mahesh-developernotes.blogspot.in/2017/03/ethereum-blockchain-private-setup-geth.html)