# web3 api in eth

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum

Since, I am not able to use the go client in the multi node mode due to a bug ([Multi node private local ethereum and send transaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9164/multi-node-private-local-ethereum-and-send-transaction)), I tried to use the c++ client eth. Tried using the go client attach to the instance and cannot seem to execute any web3 commands like in geth.

Started a test node using:

`eth --datadir ./data/test -j --no-ipc --json-rpc-port 8081 -a <coinbase-addr> --client-name 'test' --listen-ip 127.0.0.1 --listen 30001 --network-id 12321 --no-discovery`

Connect using: `geth attach rpc:http://127.0.0.1:8081`

When try admin.nodeInfo or personal.listAccounts, get errors:

```
admin.nodeInfo
ReferenceError: 'admin' is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1


personal.listAccounts
METHOD_NOT_FOUND: The method being requested is not available on this server
    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at get (web3.js:5923:38)
    at <anonymous>:1:-1
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `web3.` like this `web3.admin.nodeInfo` and `web3.personal.listAccounts`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to add the APIs `admin` and `personal` explicitly, try start the node using:

```
eth --datadir ./data/test -j --no-ipc --json-rpc-port 8081 -a <coinbase-addr> --client-name 'test' --listen-ip 127.0.0.1 --listen 30001 --network-id 12321 --no-discovery --http --http.api eth,net,admin,personal,web3
```

after try to connect with `geth attach rpc:http://127.0.0.1:8081` and repeat the requests.