# How to specify custom directory with c++ client

Tags: cpp-ethereum

With the Go client, one can use the following command to create new accounts/keystore in a specified data dir:

```
geth --datadir ./data account new
```

While using the C++ client, there is no such option:

```
eth --db-path ./data account new
```

It doesn't work. Any pointers please?

Answer (score 1):

In `eth`, you cannot use the `account new` parameter with the other options like `--db-path`.

When the first parameter to `eth` is `account`, the code at [eth/main.cpp#L425-L429](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/blob/4b805926d46bf31144e053e6898cbedd3f67e023/eth/main.cpp#L425-L429) returns the account manager code execution status:

```
if (argc > 1 && (string(argv[1]) == "wallet" || string(argv[1]) == "account"))
{
    AccountManager accountm;
    return !accountm.execute(argc, argv);
}
```

The code does not then proceed to parse the other command line options.

If you do not specify the `account` parameter in your command line, the code execution will skip the section account manager code execution section above and proceed to parse the command line options including the code to set the `datadir` at [eth/main.cpp#L589-L590](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/blob/4b805926d46bf31144e053e6898cbedd3f67e023/eth/main.cpp#L589-L590):

```
else if ((arg == "-d" || arg == "--path" || arg == "--db-path" || arg == "--datadir") && i + 1 < argc)
    setDataDir(argv[++i]);
```

So it looks like the accounts created with `account new` will have to remain in the default path, but you can change the data directory using the `--db-path` option.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using the C++ eth node client? From [HARD FORK IN LESS THAN 24 HOURS. UPGRADE YOUR CLIENT \[OFFICIAL ETHEREUM UPDATE LINKS\]](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/57z3zi/hard_fork_in_less_than_24_hours_upgrade_your/), you can see that the C++ client has not been updated for the gas reprice hard-fork. And it is much easier to work with the go-ethereum client.

Comment: Started with the go-ethereum and find it much more easier to use. The reason am trying is because of the bug in private cluster - see my earlier thread - http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9164/multi-node-private-local-ethereum-and-send-transaction